# Cannot add a new host after upgrading to MAMP Pro

Tags: laravel, mamp, mamp-pro

After upgrading to [MAMP Pro](https://www.mamp.info/en/mamp-pro/mac/), I'm not able to add a new host to serve my Laravel application. When setting up the "Document root", I point it to my Laravel's public folder and I receive the following message:

> The selected folder is a sub-folder of another host's document root, or identical to another document root! This is not allowed.

[image: Screen shot showing the error received from MAMP Pro]

It does allow me to select the directory above `public`.

I've tried to `grep` that path on my Mac to see if it's been defined somewhere else as a virtual host that I'm not aware of, and it doesn't return anything. How can I resolve this issue?

The only host defined right now on MAMP Pro is the default localhost.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that is required that the document root is in ~/Sites. After moving projects to that folder, all is fine, and possible to add new hosts without issues.